# AttributeError: Serializer object has no attribute 'initial_data', when trying to post a new request to a nested serializer in DjangoRestFramework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create two model instances from a single post request. Model2 is linked to Model1 using a `ForeignKey` field. Model1 also has a `validate()` in its serializer. The issue is when I use nested serializer to save both model instances together, the validate function of Model1 returns an error **AttributeError: 'Model1Serializer' object has no attribute 'initial_data'**.

[As per DRF docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#accessing-the-initial-data-and-instance)

> If the data keyword argument is not passed then the `.initial_data`
> attribute will not exist.

**Trials:** I tried intercepting the flow in `__init__()` and `validate()` of CombinedSerializer but it seems, the `validate()` of Model1Serializer is evaluated first.

**Doubt:** Why is the Model1Serializer not getting supplied with the `data` keyword argument and how can I correct my code? At what stage is the Model1Serializer `validate()` function evaluated?

Models:

```
from django.db import models

class Model1(models.Model):
    key1 = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.key1

class Model2(models.Model):
    foreign_key = models.ForeignKey('Model1', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    key2 = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.key2
```

Serializers:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Model1, Model2

class Model1Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def validate(self, data):
         if(self.initial_data['key1']>=10):
            data['key1'] = self.initial_data['key1'] + 1
            return data
         else:
            data['key1'] = self.initial_data['key1']
            return data
      
    class Meta:
        model = Model1
        fields = '__all__'

class Model2Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Model2
        fields = '__all__'

class CombinedModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    model1 = Model1Serializer()
    model2 = Model2Serializer()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        model2_data = validated_data.pop('model2')
        model1 = Model1.objects.create(**validated_data)
        model2 = Model2.objects.create(foreign_key=model1.id, **model2_data)
        return model1

    class Meta:
        model = Model1
        fields = '__all__'
```

Views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import generics
from .models import Model1, Model2
from .serializers import Model1Serializer, Model2Serializer, CombinedModelSerializer

class Model1List(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Model1.objects.all()
    serializer_class = Model1Serializer

class Model2List(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Model2.objects.all()
    serializer_class = Model2Serializer

class CombinedList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Model1.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CombinedModelSerializer
```

Post Request:

```
POST: http://127.0.0.1:8000/combined/

{
    "model1":
    {
        "key1": 45
    },
    "model2": {
        "key2": "val2"
    }
}
```

Package Versions:

```
Python==3.6.8
Django==2.2.4
djangorestframework==3.10.3
```

Comment: What are you going to validate in `Model1Serializer`? I don't understand what the current validator is doing.

Comment: Its just a sample validator that I've included to simplify the problem. The actual validator includes some business logic working with numbers received in the request and finally modifying the data to save in `Model1`.

Answer (score 0):

`initial_data` exists only when you pass the `data` into the constructor of the `Model1Serializer`.
But in views.py, you didn't pass it.

So if you wanna use `initial_data`, please pass that data. If you don't need them, you need to remove them in `validate` function body.

Comment: As per a [previous doubt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68610151/3608786) that I had asked on StackOverflow, I wanted to keep the view, the thinnest layer, and wanted to achieve the creation of both the `Model1` entry and `Model2` entry using the `CombinedSerializer`. Hence I was not using view to achieve this goal. Is there no way possible to achieve this using only the serializer?